# crystal report for vs2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Which version of Crystal Reports is compatible with VS 2010, and where can I get it? How do I install it with VS 2010?

If you have any tutorials please give me links.

Comment: if you install VS 2010 with all options you might get it you can't download it separately. the assumption that the version compatible with VS 2010 will also work on VS 2011 is in my opinion wrong.

Comment: Get it here: http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp

Comment: sorry 2011 is my fault I mean 2010 Thanks

Comment: which type standard or once or .....?

Comment: In VS2010 they exclude the crystal reports I read it on Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these links:

1. http://thedatafarm.com/blog/tools/visual-studio-2010-rc-and-crystal-reports-2008-ndash-just-works/
2. http://anthonystechblog.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010/
3. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317789
4. http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/crnet_install_guide_2010_en.pdf
5. http://www.sourcehints.com/articles/how-to-use-crystal-report-2010-in-vs2010.html

Answer (score 3):

I had to install it on my enterprise last week. VS2010 uses the **version 13.0** so that you have to install the crystal report runtime for it - here you have its direct download links:

> **CRVS2010    13.0.2000.0   (Links Updated in 29/10/2012)**
>
> CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_3.msi     [Download Link](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_3.zip)
>
> CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_3.msi     [Download Link](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_3.zip)

For WIN XP, WIN 2003, WIN 2008, WIN Vista, WIN 7    2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0

*Source: http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567